# Otimizando saída de Dados

Tags: python-3.x

Bom dia:

Eu fiz esse código para um exercício. A  minha dúvida é: Como eu posso otimizar as saídas sem ter que fazer vários prints. Nesse código eu fiz para três saídas. Só que se fosse para 10 saídas eu teria que fazer 10 prints.Outra dúvida que eu tenho. No texto "o valor da comissão do PRIMEIRO representante..."...esse termo...primeiro...segundo...terceiro...tem alguma forma de eu deixar ele automatizado sem eu ter que digitar um por um. Abaixo segue o meu código.

```
itens = []
item=0
valor_item = 50

for i in range(3):
    item = int(input("\nQuantidade de itens do %dº representante: " % (i+1)))
    itens.append(item)


comissoes = []
for item in itens:
    comissao = (0.1*valor_item*item) if item <= 19 else \
               (0.15*valor_item*item) if item >=20 and item<= 49 else \
               (0.20*valor_item*item) if item >=50 and item <=74 else \
               (0.25*valor_item*item) 
    comissoes.append(comissao)


print("\nValor da Comissão do do Primeiro Representante: R$ %5.2f% " %comissoes[0])
print("\nValor da Comissão do do Segundo Representante: R$ %5.2f% " %comissoes[1])
print("\nValor da Comissão do do Terceiro Representante: R$ %5.2f% " %comissoes[2])
```

Grato pela atenção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use um laço `for`, exatamente como você fez pra montar a lista `comissoes`.

```
for indice, comissao in enumerate(comissoes, start=1):
    print("\nValor da Comissão do %dº Representante: R$ %5.2f" % (indice, comissao))
```

Docs pra função `enumerate`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

---

Quanto ao seu código como um todo, você pode fazer tudo com um único laço e sem usar listas.

```
quantidade_representantes = 3
valor_item = 50

for i in range(1, quantidade_representantes + 1):
    item = int(input("\nQuantidade de itens do %dº representante: " % i))

    if item <= 19:
        multiplicador_comissao = 0.10
    elif item <= 49:
        multiplicador_comissao = 0.15
    elif item <= 74:
        multiplicador_comissao = 0.20
    else:
        multiplicador_comissao = 0.25

    comissao = multiplicador_comissao * valor_item * item

    print("Comissão do %dº representante: R$ %5.2f" % (i, comissao))
    print()
```

É só uma dica.

Comment: Poxa. Obrigado. Ajudou muito.